# Angular 4 - Angular-CLI file size vs Source-map-explorer file size

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Simply, the two files are very different.

This is the **Angular-CLI** file size: (3.59MB)

Angular CLI vendor.bundle.js

[image: Angular CLI vendor.bundle.js]

And the inspection of that same vendor in **source-map-explorer**: (1.1MB)

source map explorer vendor.bundle.js

[image: source map explorer vendor.bundle.js]

I do not seem to understand that difference.

When I run:

> ng serve --prod

I get a result of **3.59MB** instead of **1.1MB**

How do I overcome that problem?

Comment: are you on latest cli?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding --aot ?

Your CLI version might not do that by default/

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Local Angualr-CLI version and Global CLI should be updated and the same version in order for the newly AoT to work properly.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Using of `--prod` avoids creating of sourcemaps by default, you should use `--source-map` at the end of your command (it takes default value `true`) [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51277240/2940502).