# How to omit sourcemaps in Angular-CLI 6+

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to build with `ng build` without sourcemaps. In previous versions, I could use the `--no-sourcemap` or `--sourcemap=false` parameter, but now I get:

> `Unknown option: '--sourcemap'`

How can I omit source maps in Angular-CLI 6+?

Comment: did you try `--source-map`?  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#options

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `--source-map` . It takes default value `true`. So following command will not create sourcemaps:

```
ng build --source-map=false
```

Similarly `--prod` avoids creating sourcemaps by default but if you want to create then just use `--source-map` in the end to create sourcemaps.

Follow [**official Docs**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

**Update:**

For Angular cli 7 use below:

```
ng build --sourceMap=false
```

And if you want prod build with production config & bundling (thus don't want sourcemaps included in build folder) then use :

```
ng build --prod=true
```

Recent [**Official Docs**](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Answer (score 8):

You can also add sourceMap: false into the configuration of angular.json as shown below

[image]

I suppose they are false by default for production build when using Angular 6+ with cli.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, open your package.json file.

Modify `"test":"ng test"` to `"test":"ng test --source-map=false"` or to `"test":"ng test --sourceMap=false"` for your angular `CLI v6.x`

Please **note** that it is `--source-map and --sourceMap` and not `--source-maps` which can be a usual mistake.